# Bayesian Network and Conditional Independence

Tags: probability, bayesian, bayesian-network

I have the following Bayesian Network

[image]

I'm given that

> $P(q) = 0.8$
>  
>   $P(s) = 0.7$
>   $P(h|q,s)=0.75$
>   $P(h|q,\bar s)=0.85$
>   $P(h|\bar q,s)=0.15$
>   $P(h|\bar q,\bar s)=0.3$
>   $P(g|q, h) = 0.75$
>   $P(g|q, ¬h) = 0.4$
>   $P(g|¬q, h) = 0.6$
>   $P(g|¬q, ¬h) = 0.3$
>   $P(e|s) = 0.7$
>   $P(e|¬s) = 0.5$

**I'm trying to find $P(g|e)$** but I'm getting caught up using Baye's Theorem.

Using Baye's theorem I get

$P(g|e) = \frac{P(e|g)P(g)}{P(e)}$, but I get caught in a loop because I'm not sure how to solve $P(e|g)$

Can I say that because they g and e are conditionally independent, that $P(g|e) = g$?

I have found $P(g) = 0.61$, and $P(e) = .64$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I say that because they g and e are conditionally independent, that $P(g|e)=P(g)$?

No.   That would indicate independence.   Rather, they are *conditionally independent given* $s$.

---

Using the notation that $s^1:=s, s^{-1}:=\neg s$ and therefore the Law of Total Probability can be represented as: $$\begin{align}p(e) &= p(e\mid s^1)p(s^1)+p(e\mid s^{-1})p(s^{-1})\\[1ex] & =\sum_\delta p(e\mid s^\delta)p(s^\delta)&&\text{implicitly: }\delta\in\{-1,1\}\end{align}$$

Then you can say that:

$$\begin{align}p(e,g) &= \sum_\alpha p(e,g\mid s^\alpha)p(s^\alpha) &&\text{LoTP}
\\[1ex] &= \sum_\alpha p(e\mid s^\alpha)p(g\mid s^\alpha)p(s^\alpha) && \text{conditional independence}\end{align}$$

Now, use the LoTP to expand this expression into known probabilities and this find:$$p(g\mid e) = \dfrac{p(e,g)}{p(e)}$$

Comment: Does $p(e,g) = p(e|s)p(s)p(g)$?

Comment: No.  $p(e,g) = p(e\mid s)p(g\mid s)p(s)+p(e\mid\neg s)p(g\mid\neg s)p(\neg s)$

Comment: Why is it $(g|s)$?

Comment: @JasonDor Because they are conditionally independent.  $p(e,g\mid s) = p(e\mid s)p(g\mid s)$

Comment: Just for my understanding, if it were $p(e|g)$, then they would be conditionally independent on $q, h$?

Comment: No, $p(e,g) ~=~ p(g\mid e)p(e) ~=~ p(e\mid g)p(g)$ regardless. It has naught to do with dependency of $g$ on $q,h,s$.  It is just no help in finding what you want .  Your next task is to expand $p(g\mid s^\alpha)$ using your laws of total probability.